# Salesforce SSO using Elastic SSO fails

Tags: single-sign-on

I have set up the SSO Identity Provider using Elastic SSO and then configured Salesforce as a Service Provider. I also configured the Salesforce Single Sign On Settings. I then try to login and it fails. Using the SAML Assertion Validator, I get the following error.

How do fix this and proceed?

10. Checking the Recipient

Incorrect recipient

Recipient that we found in the assertion: https://login.salesforce.com

Recipient that we expected based on the Single Sign-On Settings page: https://login.salesforce.com/?saml=MgoTx78aEPAJqzCg_w1AV_y6G_ttt5ZN.XpTfVysTSfKW58vyVRFlFzOLK or https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?saml=MgoTx78aEPAJqzCg_w1AV_y6G_ttt5ZN.XpTfVysTSfKW58vyVRFlFzOLK

11. Validating the Signature

Is the response signed? true

Is the assertion signed? true

The reference in the response signature is valid

The signature in the assertion is not valid

The reference in the assertion signature is valid

Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? true

Signature or certificate problems

The signature in the response is not valid

Comment: The Recipient must match the AssertionConsumerServiceURL sent in the SAML Request. Also the certificate needs to be configured as part of the SSO Settings on Salesforce. Useful blog http://blog.rhysgoodwin.com/cloud/salesforce-sso-with-adfs-2-0-everything-you-need-to-know/